# LLVM instrumentation without IR builder

Tags: llvm

I need to do heavy instrumentation using a LLVM pass. I want to avoid the IR Builder because it is somehow complicated and the code looks really messy. Isn't there a more convenient way to create LLVM IR? I think of a way where I can use for example C/C++ to create the instrumented code.

Comment: The IRBuilder *is* the convenient way to create LLVM IR (and it is C++).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not use the IR Builder for my [instrumentation](http://bprail.github.io/contech/).  Most of the instrumentation is accomplished with two steps:

1. The LLVM pass identifies the instructions of interest and inserts function calls to the requisite instrumentation routine.
2. The instrumentation routines are written in C files and compiled and linked into the final program.  Using link-time optimization (LTO), this approach achieves good performance by removing the function calls and directly inserting the machine code for the library instrumentation routines.

Therefore, most of the instrumentation is C code that clang compiles down to necessary IR.

Other pieces of instrumentation have to be crafted dynamically, so the IR is constructed by invoking the appropriate XYZInst::Create calls, where XYZ is the specific instruction.

The first approach is closer to what you desire; however, it required writing a separate script to act as the compiler driver and managing Makefiles, libraries, et cetera.